# Can I change the name seen on my apps on the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've have made a few apps and they have my name on them as the developer. Is there a way I can change the name of the developer of existing apps?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my surname in the account display.

I could change with a ticket through the link:
https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

They will ask you some proof documents such as ID.

Comment: Otherwhise you can now migrate apps to another account. Depends on what you want to do